# Regridding netcdf file with mass conservation

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I tried to regrid a netcdf file with CO2-emission data to a coarser grid covering the same area and mean monthly values of 12 month. The data has 3 dimensions (time, latitude, longitude).
To check if mass conservation was achieved, I tried to simply sum up the variables of both my old and new netcdf file like this:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np


ds_original = xr.open_dataset('original.nc')

ds_regrid = xr.open_dataset('regrid.nc')


#selecting emissions from first month of ncfiles
ds_original = ds_original[dict(time=slice(0, 1))]
emis_original = ds_original.variables['CO2'][0]

ds_regrid = ds_regrid[dict(time=slice(0, 1))]
emis_regrid = ds_regrid.variables['CO2'][0]

print(np.nansum(emis_original.variables))
print(np.nansum(emis_regrid.variables))
```

The outputs are very different values, 32 for the regridded and 3300 for the original file.
Does someone know where I'm going wrong? I'm grateful for every hint!

Comment: You will need to provide more details. What are the units? How did you regrid things? You seem to be saying code went wrong, but are not showing the code

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used cdo for the regridding, which I ran directly from the terminal. The command is 'cdo remapcon,new_grid original.nc regrid.nc' and should provide mass conservation but I would like to check. The unit is g CO2/m². I think the code is fine but the way I summed up the emissions 'np.nansum(emis.variables)' might be wrong.

Comment: It looks like you need to multiply by area